# What to do with abandoned questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, flagging

We have a large amount of abandoned or zombie questions. They keep popping up as modified by community...

For most of them there there is not enough info to answer, but the user never bothered updating the post.

What is the best way to close such "abandoned" questions.

The tag **unclear on what you are asking** doesn't really apply for most of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [Old, abandoned questions with unaccepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135019/278094) we should not close a question just to get rid of it.

We should **not** be closing questions like [Sharp edges while maintaining circular shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35970/2217), [Custom trackpad pan/zoom/rotate behavior add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1803/2217), [Using a BI texture in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/49129/2217), [Creases at cutoff parts of normal map wrap](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/36934/2217), etc.

Here is an example of one that I CVed: [Blender will not render audio visualizer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44347/2217).
There is no way to ever answer (for one thing it may be a hardware issue, but that is besides the point of this answer), the OP was asked for clarification but never responded. Yes his problem maybe *clear*, "my render not working now" but that does not make an answerable question. We need more info from to even guess what is going on. That is exactly the type that should of been closed 5 months ago; questions that are vague enough so that it will get guesses at best, and likely low quality "maybe you should try" type of answers.

(Last example) [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44628/2217) should be Dved, and closed. It is unclear, and not even very understandable.

In this [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261327/278094) it is suggested to close as unclear.

Jeff Atwood (SE founder) responding ([Unresponsive askers abandon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89162/278094)) about questions that are very specific to the OP, says that it is ok to just delete those.

Finally the SE system will automatically delete questions meeting the following criteria:

- Closed more than 9 days ago
- Not closed as a duplicate
- Score <= 0
- Not locked
- No answers with a score > 0
- No accepted answer
- No pending reopen votes
- No edits in the past 9 days

[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/278094)

---

Now while you are going through the [unanswered list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered), don't just CV the bad ones.

- Edit any questions to make them better. Then they might just get answered.
- Edit any so so answers, when they become good answer they will get UVs, which will draw more attention to the question.
- UV any good answers and questions, just because it is unanswered does not make it a bad question.
- Answer (now who would think of a thing like that) any that just slipped through the cracks.
- Don't be afraid to DV bad questions and answers, if it is a "bad" post DV it.